# Spring Security with JSF

Tags: jsf, spring-security

Two problems:

**Problem 1:**

I've got the following in my `applicaitonContext-security.xml` file:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsf" servlet-api-provision="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied.jsf" filters="none" />     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsf" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/redirect.html" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" filters="none" />      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/a4j_resource/**" filters="none" />        
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsf" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf" default-target-url="/redirect.html" />     
    <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/summary/projects.jsf` I don't get redirected to the `login.jsf` page. Any ideas.

**Problem 2:**
In the `projects.xhtml` page I have

```
<rich:comboBox  value="#{projectUiService.coordinatorSelected}"  directInputSuggestions="true"  defaultLabel="Enter Co-ordinator" >
```

On the `getCoordinatorSelected` method I have `@RolesAllowed("READ_PROJECT")` but all I  get is the error:

```
AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

How do I get Spring to redirect to the logon page when a user is not logged in, and how do I get it to redirect to the `denied.jsf` page if the user does not have the correct rights?

I've looked around for the last 6 hrs and tried loads of logging, but can not find a solution. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
@[Maksym Demidas] was correct. Inherited an application which used a combination of Spring 2.5 and 3. Sorted out all dependencies to Spring 3 and updated security xml file as:

```
....
<security:http pattern="/denied.jsf" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/login.jsf" security="none"/>
....
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsf" servlet-api-provision="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsf" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsf" authentication-failure-url="/login.jsf" default-target-url="/redirect.html" />
    <security:logout />
</security:http>
```

Now all works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace all your

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/denied.jsf" filters="none" />
```

constructions by separate

```
<security:http pattern="/denied.jsf" security="none" />
```

tags. One intercept-url with filters="none" [will deactivate all your http config element](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-intercept-url-filters)

Second option:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/denied.jsf" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Comment: `<security:http pattern="/denied.jsf" filters="none" />` is not alowed as a child element of a parent `<security:http>` tag.

Comment: Yes. you need multiple top level <security:http> tags.

Comment: Solved it! Please see answer below for a full explanation. Thanks Maksym.